# Arguments for C functions that are called in Python

Tags: python, c, swig, ctypes

I am relatively new to Python and C. What I want to do is to combine the efficiency of C and simplicity of Python.

My task is to do some large scale computation, in which case Matlab (have been using it for long time) cannot support. Therefore I consider turn to C for higher efficiency, with help of intel MKL. However, it is not easy to do data visualization in C and I think it would be better to do it in Python/Matplotlib (Matlab can do that but I don't want to use it :-).

Firstly, I can compile C files into an executable and call it in Python through `os.system("foo")`. But that is not convenient to adjust parameters for my models (too many cases). Things like `main(int argc, char *argv)` might be of help. But I think that is not good enough.

Then, I find SWIG. By compiling and wrapping the C files as a .so file, I can do something in Python like,

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.my_mod(7, 2)
```

where `foo` is from `_foo.so` generated by SWIG. Function `my_mod` is defined in a c file as

```
int my_mod(int x, int y) {
  return (x%y);
}
```

Till now, everything is ok. However, then I don't really know how to call my C functions if their arguments include arrays/pointers, because I will have to define input to C in Python. For example, if I change the above C function into,

```
int *my_mod(int *x, int *y) {
  blablabla;
}
```

Then how do I prepare `x` and `y` and receive its returned pointer in Python? Hoping somebody could give me some hints.

PS: It seems `ctypes` can be used, but I am still struggling with this.

OS info:
Ubuntu 12.04, Python 2.7.6, gcc 4.6.3, SWIG 2.0.4, Intel/MKL 11.1

Comment: Have you looked at [Cython](http://cython.org/)?

Comment: The [`ctypes` tutorial](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html) has a lot of really useful tips and tricks for using it.  If you set up the `argtypes` of a function to the correct values (e.g. `POINTER(c_int)`), then it's straightforward to pass an array of values in.

Comment: The SWIG docs have examples for using pointers and arrays in [34.7 Tips and techniques](http://www.swig.org/Doc2.0/Python.html#Python_nn45).

Comment: SciPy tutorial on ctypes may be a bit overwhelming, but may be worth looking at: http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/Ctypes#head-7998d0c1cf0e82283a8fdcd0e5c63e0fa36d832c

Comment: But there's a more concise tutorial as well: http://jjd-comp.che.wisc.edu/index.php/PythonCtypesTutorial